# Question-tag structure for "needn't have +p.p

Tags: tag-questions

How to form the tag question for sentence like this:
**She needn't have studied English.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an unusual sentence in Present-Day English, because it follows the now old-fashioned use of *need* as a *modal verb* in negative and interrogative contexts. As a modal, *need* is an auxiliary, and should head the tag question:

> She needn't have studied English, need she?

Although grammatical, that's so century-before-last that it would startle most hearers. Even people who still use *need* as a modal would probably recast the sentence using *need* in the ordinary way, as a chaining verb with *do* support, to avoid this:

> She doesn't need to have studied English, does she?